Is there a way to maintain information in an iframe when i change tabs?
I have a webpage with several tabs. Inside one of them I include an iframe as a way to manage certain properties, therefore I need the data to be persistent. Each time I change to another tab and come back the Iframe reloads, losing the state of the variables. How do I make sure the iframe doesn't unmount each time I leave the tab?
I use a framework called Marcelle that has a class for creating each tab and the final view.
I can create new components with two files.One is a view.svelte
  import { ViewContainer } from '@marcellejs/design-system';
  export let title;
  export let url;  // Accept the URL prop
</script>

<ViewContainer {title}>
  {#if url}
    <iframe title="" src={url}  width="(parseInt(window.innerWidth) * 0.9)" height="750px" style="border: none;"></iframe>
  {/if}
</ViewContainer>

<style>
  .my-color {
    color: seagreen;
  }
</style>


and the other one is a component.js
import { Component } from '@marcellejs/core';
import View from './widget.view.svelte';

export class Widget extends Component {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        super();
        this.title = '';
        this.options = options;
        this.url = options.url || '';  // Accept a URL option to embed the webpage
    }

    mount(target) {
        const t = target || document.querySelector(`#${this.id}`);
        if (!t) return;
        this.destroy();
        this.$$.app = new View({
            target: t,
            props: {
                title: this.title,
                options: this.options,
                url: this.url  // Pass URL to the view
            }
        });
    }
}


I haven't found anything that works within this framework.

See also: Prevent to reload tab content when changing between tabs (duplicate?).

This question is similar to: Angular 5: Prevent to reload tab content when changing between tabs. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need to hide the iframe via CSS, instead of removing it from the page via JS. The way you are doing it currently is forcing the iframe to be reloaded each time you show it on the page.

Hi! Thanks for the comment. However, I am not sure this will work for my case, since each tab is a separate view. Therefore, the tab where I am embedding the iframe is separate from the others.  Furthermore, I am using a framework called Marcelle, that is based on svelte, so it is quite limited in terms of components I am able to edit.

Then you need to find another framework, as this is the only way it can be done.
